# Checking if page event fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Im aware this may be a slightly odd question, but given a Page class that looks like this:

```
    public class abc:Control
    {
      public abc()
      {
        this.Init+=new EventHandler(foo);
        this.Load+=new EventHandler(foo);
      }    

      void foo(object sender, eventargs e)
      {
        //determine whether or not this.Init has already fired.
      }
    }
```

I know I could do this by setting a global boolean 'hasinitfired', but I was wondering if this was not necessary or if something as part of the .net library already existed.

Comment: Not an answer, but small note: do not forget to unsubscribe the events because it could cause memory leaks

Comment: are you sure the GC wont take care of that?

Comment: The question is more abstract than that - you're looking for a way to identify if certain method was executed from within the method itself. By the way, `abc` is not Page, it's just a Control.

Comment: it's fine to not unsubscribe the events in this case, as the events are bound within the same class. if another class were handling the events, then yes you should unbind to give the GC a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to know init is fired or not. Init always gets fired during postback or callback. Go through ASP.net page lifecycle, and you will know what all events fired after init and what all before. If you intend to use same handler for different events, yes make a class variable to identify the current event. I recommend attach different handler, and call another method with different param value.

like,

```
 public class abc:Control
    {
      public abc()
      {
        this.Init+=new EventHandler(foo1);
        this.Load+=new EventHandler(foo2);
      }    

      void foo1(object sender, eventargs e)
      {
        foo('init');
      }
      void foo2(object sender, eventargs e)
      {
        foo('load');
      }
      void foo(string from)
      {
         // do something
      }

    }
```

This will give cleaner solution and flexibility to add functionality.

Comment: you are not right saying the **Page.Init** is allways fired. The **Page.Init** event is fired inside the **Page.OnInit** method so as long as it is virtual you may redefine the method so the event won't be fired.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to know if init has fired when foo runs. As @Adam said, tracing would let you do that if you wanted to see what your app was doing.

Whilst it's running, the best way as I see it would be with a flag, as you suggested.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you'd use the .NET `Trace` class for.  You can use trace to put text in the Visual Studio output window.

`Trace.WriteLine("Method called.");`

Tracing in .NET has more options than my example:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020910.htm

Even further to this, you could use a PostSharp aspect to decorate this method, but that is a third party library.